# Is there a way to filter multiple columns in excel simultaneously without one filter influencing the next filter?

Tags: excel, vba

I am working on an excel worksheet where the there are 3 columns with certain cells highlighted yellow. The hihglighted cells in one column are in no way related to the highlighted cells in other columns. My agenda is to filter all the rows with the highlighted cells. The problem is if I apply filter in one column, the filter in next column will work only on the rows available after the previous thus excluding the other rows I need in my final result.

I can think of using for loop to check each cell individually for its colour and showing the corresponding row and hiding the rest.

Another option would be record the row number when I am highlighting the cells in the beginning. That way I will have the rows listed that need to be shown in the end.

Is there any other way readymade/easier to filter in such scenarios?

Comment: You could create an (maybe invisible) column that holds TRUE if the row needs to be displayed and FALSE if not. Depending on your logic, Use a formula or VBA code to fill it.

Comment: Wow, that is a very simple and easy to implement solution. Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: Another option would be to use the `Advanced Filter`